# Recursion in a for loop to iteration

Tags: c++, recursion

I am generalizing another problem I have that has a similar recursive call. In my case, the variables being used are strings, so I can't simply pass by value to avoid the code before and after the recursive call in the loop. Is there a way to turn this into an iterative loop? Please assume that the code before and after the recursive call in the loop cannot be changed to make this specific instance work.

This code tests to see if the sum of any combintion of ints from nums adds up to zero. The original value for index is 0, and max is the maximum number of numbers I want to add up in any given solution.

For further clarification, the numbers can be repeated, so I can't just try all possible combinations, because there are infinitely many.

```
void findSolution(const vector<int>& nums, vector<int>& my_list, int& mySum,
int index, const int max)
{
    if(mySum == 0) {
        /* print my_list and exit(0) */
    }
    if(index < max) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
            my_list.push_back(nums[i]);
            mySum += nums[i];
            findSolution(nums, my_list, mySum, index+1, max);
            mySum -= nums[i];
            my_list.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So... you want us to replace *that one line* with something else, to make the whole thing non-recursive and get the right answer?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the recursion? If you think it will magically speed up your program, you should focus on fixing the algorithm. As written, your code checks way too many combinations, because it's not aware that the sum of the same numbers in a different order is still the same sum. (It's not clear to me whether you intend to allow the answer to have repeated values from nums, but if you don't, you're also checking all of those possibilities too, which is wasteful and potentially results in the wrong answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a manual stack.

In your case the only independent states of the recursive call are the value of I and the value of index.  Index is just the recursive call depth.

Create a std vector of int called your stack, reserve it to max.  Replace the loop with while stack true.

Before entering the loop, push zero on the stack.

Break the cod in your loop into 3 parts.  A B and C.  A is before recursive call, B is what you recursively call, and C is after.  Included in C is the increment at the top of the loop, which happens after C in the original code.

The first thing you do in the loop is check if the top of the stack is nums size or bigger.  If so, pop the stack, then execute C and continue unless stack is empty, in which case break.

Then execute A.  Then push 0 on the stack and continue if the stack size is less than max.  Then execute C.  You can remove the C code duplication with a flag variable.

Remember that the top of the stack replaces any references to I.  Basically we are replacing a recursive call which automatically makes a stack for us with manually maintaining the same stack, but only storing the absolute least amount we can get away with.  The start of the loop does double duty as both the end of a recursive call and the start of the loop, so we can do away with goto.

Give it a try, and worry about the explanation after you have seen it.  The stuff about the flag variable makes more sense after the code is in place.